# Loading headers from SecureStore in apisauce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

All the endpoints in the backend require `Authorization` header. This header is stored in `SecureStore`.

### Problem Statement

I want to load the `Authorization` header ( JWT Token ), for every API call after logging in.
Now this requires an `async` operation i.e.`authStorage.getToken`.

This is my `client.js` ( the apisauce client ).

**client.js**

```js
import { create } from "apisauce";
import authStorage from "../auth/storage";
import IP from "../config/network";

const restoreToken = async () => {
  return await authStorage.getToken("idToken");
};

const apiClient = (auth_token = "") =>
  create({
    baseURL: "http://" + IP + ":8990",
    headers: { Authorization: auth_token }, // This I've added later
  });

export default apiClient;
```

This is the `PostsApi` which uses `apiClient` to make the calls.

**PostsApi.js**

```js
import apiClient from "./client";

const endpoint = "/api/";
const bookmarkEndpoint = "/bookmark/";
const getPosts = (last_id = 0, limit = 10) => {
  return apiClient.get(endpoint + "?last_id=" + last_id + "&limit=" + limit);
};

const toggleBookmark = (item_id) => {
  return apiClient.get(bookmarkEndpoint + "?item_id=" + item_id);
};

export default {
  getPosts,
  toggleBookmark,
};
```

#### My Understanding

I understand that if I can add the header in `client.js` itself, it would be injected everytime there's an API call.
I've tried :

```js
const restoreToken = async () => {
  return await authStorage.getToken("idToken");
};
```

But I am not sure how to call this async operation in `client.js`

#### Bonus Question

This token ( `idToken` ) would be reloaded every hour, so it's best to get the token from `SecureStore` everytime instead of saving it once.

Thanks.

### Accepted answer and what worked for me

**Worked for me**
apisauce's `setHeader` : [Documented here](https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce#changing-headers)

Accepted answer is a detailed drilling of the axios setting up of headers. So if someone's using axios client directly they can see the accepted answer else, if you're an `apisauce` user, use the `setHeader` functionality provided with the library.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You will have to store your token with the state (can be redux or local state).
2. During save/refresh/reload the token, you will have set headers of the HTTP client.

You can set header using below command (example)

```
export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ''
  delete apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']

  if (token) {
    apiClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
  }
}
```

Call the above function to set a token during reload/refresh/creation of token.

```
const restoreToken = async () => {
  return await authStorage.getToken("idToken").then(token =>  setAuthToken(token));
};
```